# How can I use RedirectToAction within a base controller class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Right now I'm in the process of converting a web application to an MVC 2 website. I have a base controller which all my other controllers inherit from. I have some business logic I've placed in an overridden Execute method that, if need be, will redirect a user to an action.

Every controller action needs to run this same logic and I didn't want to put calls to my function in every action method. I wanted a central place to place the code. In the old website I had this logic run within a master page load event, but transitioning this logic to MVC 2 has been challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `ExecuteResult` method on the returned `ActionResult`.

Also, you should override `ExecuteCore`, not `Execute`.  Otherwise, you lose the `ControllerContext`.

By the way, you should consider [writing an ActionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232768.aspx) and [loading it dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309182.aspx).

Comment: I love the concept of ActionFilters. This will definitely be an implementation going forward. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when the code needs to run, you can override the OnActionExecuting and/or OnActionExecuted methods in your base controller class.

Comment: He's overriding `ExecuteCore`.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put below code in your every controllers. (Before Construction)

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    //You function here
}
```

Please remember to write your function in one class. if there's any modification occurs, you don't have to change the controllers again.